# implementing Blazor in an ASP.NET Core site - components don't render in views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I've followed every step in this article: https://waelkdouh.medium.com/integrating-blazor-components-into-existing-asp-net-core-mvc-applications-b1a2aec4ac1f

I've created a file named MyFirst.razor in the Components/Pages folder, but it doesn't render when referenced in Index.cshtml as .

**Components.Pages/MyFirst.razor**

```
 @page "/my-first"

<h3>Current count: @count</h3>

@code {
    private int count = 0;

    private void HandleClick()
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@using LC.BlazorTest.Components.Pages
   
<h1>Velkommen - blaze up</h1>

<MyFirst />
```

**Index page source:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />

<title>BlazorBlazor</title>

<link href="/IMAGE/fav-icon.png" rel="icon" type="text/CSS" />

<link href="/STYLE/Creator/Creator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" />


</head>
<body>
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        


<h1>Velkommen - blaze up</h1>

<MyFirst />

    </main>

    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="/SCRIPT/Creator/Creator.js" type="application/JAVASCRIPT"></script>

<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c237ba9e1f.js" type="application/JAVASCRIPT"></script>



    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

the  tag hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to render a Blazor component into an MVC view. As far as I know, it is not that simple.

You may want to use the `component` tag helper to render Blazor components in cshtml views.

Unfortunately, MVC views are rendered once on the server, so you can not simply just put a component name like with your regular Blazor app.

You can prerender the component (it will remain static), use server-side rendering or client-side rendering (WebAssembly). It may be a little bit tricky tho since you mix multiple rendering styles together. In short, use

```
<component type="typeof(MyFirst)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

instead of

```
<MyFirst />
```

when writing in cshtml files (MVC pages/views).

Checkout [render modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.rendermode?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or [prerendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#render-components-from-a-page-or-view)